# Need the name of algebraic structure suitable for this

Tags: abstract-algebra, rational-numbers, binary-operations

If I want to prove that addition and multiplication are internal operations in the rational domain Q.
What algebrac structure I need to prove that `(Q,+, *)` will be?

For example:
`(Q,+, *)`  need be a field, a ring ...
or prove that `(Q,+)` and `(Q, *)` are groups both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much less that any of that. All you need to prove is that addition and multiplication are binary operations from $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ into $\mathbb Q$ (that is, that $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ and $(\mathbb{Q},\times)$ are groupoids).